# SQL 2005 find duplicate indexes

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2005, scripting

I've created the following script to pull up duplicate indexes on my DB but I need to find a way to implement it across all the databases on the SQL server - any suggestions?`

```
with indexcols as
(

select object_id as id, index_id as indid, name,
(select case keyno when 0 then NULL else colid end as [data()]
from sys.sysindexkeys as k
where k.id = i.object_id
and k.indid = i.index_id
order by keyno, colid
for xml path('')) as cols,
(select case keyno when 0 then colid else NULL end as [data()]
from sys.sysindexkeys as k
where k.id = i.object_id
and k.indid = i.index_id
order by colid
for xml path('')) as inc
from sys.indexes as i
)
select
object_schema_name(c1.id) + '.' + object_name(c1.id) as 'table',
c1.name as "index",
c2.name as "exactduplicate"
from indexcols as c1
join indexcols as c2
on c1.id = c2.id
and c1.indid < c2.indid
and c1.cols = c2.cols
and c1.inc = c2.inc;
```

Comment: have you looked at sp_msforeachdb to apply this to each db?   You would want to add some logic to exclude system databases probably :)

Comment: thanks - had issues using it because of cross compatabaility

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid msforeachdb it has been known to miss databases, which I have experienced first person.

Either create your own cursor(opportunity to learn something new!), or use Aaron Bertrand's reliable version. [sp_ineachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others in that msforeachdb has problems.  Using Aaron Bertrand's [sp_foreachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior), you should be able to use the following example:

(The question mark [?] basically acts like a placeholder for each enumerated database.)

```
EXEC sp_foreachdb @command = N'
use ?;
select ''?'';
with indexcols as
(
select object_id as id, index_id as indid, name,
(select case keyno when 0 then NULL else colid end as [data()]
from [?].sys.sysindexkeys as k
where k.id = i.object_id
and k.indid = i.index_id
order by keyno, colid
for xml path('''')) as cols,
(select case keyno when 0 then colid else NULL end as [data()]
from sys.sysindexkeys as k
where k.id = i.object_id
and k.indid = i.index_id
order by colid
for xml path('''')) as inc
from [?].sys.indexes as i
)
select
object_schema_name(c1.id) + ''.'' + object_name(c1.id) as ''table'',
c1.name as "index",
c2.name as "exactduplicate"
from indexcols as c1
join indexcols as c2
on c1.id = c2.id
and c1.indid < c2.indid
and c1.cols = c2.cols
and c1.inc = c2.inc;
'
    ,@suppress_quotename = 1
    ,@user_only = 1;
```

Comment: This script doesn't seem to work - think theres a few issues - tried to correct - ie sp_MSforeachdb

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problems you're having with the original script?

Comment: the original script worked fine - the one i posted - i just wanted it to run on every table on every database.

Comment: And that is what the version that I posted in my answer does - so, what problem are you having with the script I posted?

Comment: Well first issue: Could not find stored procedure: sp_foreachdb - i corrected this to sp_msforeachdb then we get another error: Procedure or function 'sp_MSforeachdb' expects parameter '@command1', which was not supplied.

Comment: As stated in my answer, you need to get the sp_foreachdb sp from this link (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) and create in your master database (or really any database) and then run the example in my original answer

Comment: clearly i've switched off and gone home for xmas early! Sorry. Think it doesn't like the fact that some databases don't have an entry on the table. Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'dbnamehere'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact TSQL code you're trying to run?  'dbnamehere' sounds like you've pulled an 'example' of TSQL code and are trying to run that.

Comment: I put that in there instead of putting the long db name on the net